# Can an aftermarket Android radio cause an airbag to malfunction?

Tags: electronics, lexus, supplemental-restraint-system, head-unit, rx350

I would like to upgrade my 2007 Lexus RX350 factory radio to the following unit.

[image]

But I am learning the passenger airbag indicator won't function the same as the factory unit. From an engineering perspective, could this unit cause the passenger airbag or any airbag for that matter, to malfunction?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The indicator is just a simple LED that gets a control to come on/flash from the airbag module. Long as the replacement has an indicator for it if should be fine.

How ever if there is no indicator then the airbag module will know this and it will cause an error in the airbag system. Usually when the airbag module has faults/error codes stored they turn the airbag system off to prevent malfunction.

Comment: Thank you, do you mean there would be an error on the dash with the speedometer?

Comment: It stores the code in the airbag computer but yes it would display an error message on the dash.